# Looking for a manga involving a female lead with magic powers who seeks own standing

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead is a down to earth girl with powerful magic, not heavy on fight scenes, rather she overpowers opposition with magic or fists when it come to violence or intimidation, though the lead has great intelligence as well. Main scene that sticks in memory is when requested by a neighboring royalty (term used because can't remember if he was a king, prince, or other title though he was ruling) to go undercover in his harem to destroy it from the inside, as the members in question had to man ties to nobility for the royal in question to do it himself.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely [The Magician Wants Normality](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=146625), as identified in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250114).

> One day, Kosaka Mitsuki was abruptly sent on a trip to a different
> world. She was an otaku, so she adapted really fast. Then she decided
> to live her life as a magician.
>
> She made a living by making full use of the benefits of the
> automaticly translated knowledge and language of her original world.
> But reality was harsh.
>
> She was keenly aware that she was handling ‘Bishie’ from this
> different world who could easily conquer a maiden hearts and dreams.

Shortly after meeting the prince, he asks her to help a friend of his (the king of a nearby country) bring down his harem by infiltrating it from the inside and provoking the other women.